# Passing function name as parameter of Another function in C++ class

Tags: c++, function

I have two classes A and B.  I want to pass a function name in class A as parameter of function in Class B.  I tried with below sample, Is it correct way.

```
class A
{
  public:
  B m_b;

  void MyFun()
  {
      // do something
  }

  void Test()
  {
  m_b.Process( MyFun );
  } 
}


class B
{
 public:
 void Process( void (*f)() )
 {
   (*f)();
 }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you tried, then you should tell what failed or what worked ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MyFun` is a member function of class `A`, you need a pointer-to-member instead of a regular function pointer, and you also need an instance of class `A` to invoke the function on:

```
class B
{
 public:
 void Process(A *obj, void (A::*f)() )
 {
   (obj->*f)();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if `MyFun` is not a static member of your class, it has a hidden argument that is of type `A*`, so this is implemented like: `m_a.MyFun(...)` =~ `MyFunImpl(&m_a, ...)`.

So, What you want is probably have a static function `MyFun` (you can't use `this` inside it), and inside `B::Process` call `f()`.

If you need to pass `this`, refer to `casablanca`'s answer (pointers to member functions).

Otherwise, if you want to pass an argument, you can lookup `std::bind` or lambda functions (C++0x), or `boost::bind` prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the advice here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.4, you'll end up with this:

```
class A;
typedef void (A::*MemFun)();

class B 
{ 
 public: 
 void Process(A& a, MemFun mf) 
 { 
   (a.*mf)(); 
 } 
}; 

class A 
{ 
  public: 
  B m_b; 

  void MyFun() 
  { 
    // do something 
  } 

  void Test() 
  { 
    MemFun p = &A::MyFun;
    A a;
    m_b.Process(a, p); 
  }  
};
```